# How to get value from select in which there is preselected option in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using this code to show the dropdown to the user. When the form is submitted I am using `$_POST['newproduct']` to get the value. Variable `$isNewProduct` can be `0 or 1` only.

#### index.php

```
<?php
    require "db.php";
    $link = mysqli_connect($_srvr, $_user, $_pass, $_db);
    $query = "SELECT `new_product` FROM `products` WHERE `id`=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
    $isNewProduct = $row[0];
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <select name="newproduct">
        <option value="0" <?php echo $isNewProduct ? "" : "selected" ; ?> >No</option>
        <option value="1" <?php echo $isNewProduct ? "selected" : "" ; ?> >Yes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update_info_btn" />
</form>
```

#### update.php

```
if( isset($_POST['update_info_btn']) ) {
    $new_product = $_POST['newproduct'];
    // query to update the row with $new_product in DB.
}
```

Now if `$isNewProduct = 1` then option 'YES' is preselected, when the option is changed to 'NO' and form is submitted, `$_POST['newproduct']` always gives `1`.

Likewise, I have one more dropdown in which I have around 20 options and one is preselected when the form is submitted after changing the option, it always gives that preselected value.

Comment: Show more of your PHP. How do you determine what value you are getting? Are you saving `$_POST['newproduct']` to the variable `$newproduct` and then later overwriting it?

Comment: @Mike sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: So you have `$isNewProduct`, `$new_product` and `$_POST['newproduct']`... You sure you're not confusing one for the other somewhere?

Comment: It will be great if you show where you assign value for `$isNewProduct`

Comment: Is that your *whole* update.php file? Where's the line that shows `$_POST['newproduct']` with the incorrect value?

Comment: The line `<option value="1" <?php echo $isNewProduct ? "selected" : "" ; ?> >Yes</option` is missing the `>` at the end. Add that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Mike I am not echoing out the value, I check the DB, if the change happens or not.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for pointing it out, but that's not causing the problem.

Comment: `I am not echoing out the value` -- well you *should* be. You assumed that the value PHP got from the form is always 1 but you didn't check that. Whenever debugging your scripts you need to make sure that at every step of the way, starting at the beginning, that your variables contain the values you would expect them to, and if not, figure out why. If PHP gets the correct value then the error is in your DB update code and everything else you have up to this point in your question is irrelevant.

Comment: @Lepanto I have updated the code. Thanks

Comment: @Mike Thanks, update query was incorrect. I will remember this for whole my life.

Comment: @RaghavGarg Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following code...

```
<?php
$newproduct='';
if(isset($_POST['newproduct'])
{
    $newproduct=$_POST['newproduct'];
}
?>
<select name="newproduct">
        <option value="0" <?php if($newproduct ==0){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >No</option>
         <option value="1" <?php if($newproduct ==1){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That can be simplified to `$newproduct = (isset($_POST['newproduct'])) ? $_POST['newproduct'] : 0;`, but I'm not entirely sure if that's what the OP wants. I assumed `$newproduct` came from the DB or somewhere and is not always `0` by default. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Dear @Mike OP said that `$isNewProduct can be 0 or 1 only.` , so that why i have taken $isNewProduct,= 0 now edited default value thanx for pointing..

Comment: Actually how you have it now makes it less clear what you're doing. Comparing an empty string to integers is, in my opinion at least, error prone and not quite so obvious to what you are trying to do. Error prone because `"" == 1` is `true`, but `"" == "1"` is `false`, so if somewhere along the line your integer gets cast to a string your code fails here. However like I said, I don't know where `$newproduct` comes from, so the OP will have to clarify that. As it is now it's unclear.

Comment: okay, thank you for this information, I'm not much experienced like you, but i always tried to do my best, to help someone..